# Assert equals 2 lists

Tags: java, testng

Trying to assert 2 lists but it fails:

[image]

I'm trying to compare two `List` objects.

Here's my test class.

```
public class RestServiceTest {

    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Test
    public void getAllEmployeesTest() throws IOException {
        HttpResponse response = http.get("http://localhost:8087/employee");
        List<Employee> expectedList = new ArrayList<>();
        expectedList.add(new Employee(2, "Yashwant", "Chavan", 30, false));
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Employee>>() {}.getType();

        List<Employee> actualList = gson.fromJson(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()), listType);
        System.out.println(actualList);
        System.out.println(expectedList);
        Assert.assertEquals(actualList,expectedList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you overridden `equals` (and `hashCode`) in `Employee`?

Comment: Show the text of the error as text in the question.

Comment: Note that the arguments are the other way around. It's `assertEquals(expected, actual)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing your code, you add a new `Employee` in your expectedList giving that object a unique reference. The actual list will have another instance of `Employee` with another unique reference making these two different objects.

Although the two objects have the same fields, the `assertEquals` for list will use the equals method within `Employee` to check if the objects are the same. If you haven't implemented the `equals` method yourself inside Employee it will check on those unique references I mentioned before.

A solution would be to override the `equals` method in `Employee` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if(!obj instanceof Employee) {
      return false;
   }
   Employee e = (Employee) obj;
   // Add more fields to compare if necessary
   return this.getEmployeeId().equals(e.getEmployeeId()) && this.getAge().equals(e.getAge()); 
 }
```

which should give you the results you're hoping for. [Possible similar issue and probably better explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31032752/3450674)

As mentioned by @Zabuza you also need to override `hashCode` as well in case you use something like a `HashMap` in combination with `Employee`. Further explanation about `hashCode can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707554/3450674).

Comment: Don't forget to mention that when overriding `equals` one **must** always override `hashCode` too. Else *terrible things* will happen.

Comment: @Zabuza valid point, I added a reference to an other question addressing `hashCode`

Answer (score 0):

See the `Collection` documentation: [you should implement/override equals method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). Otherwise when comparing two collections (e.g. `List`s of `Employee`s) each item will be compared on its object id.
(Also, remember to implement `Employee.hashCode()` method too.)

Answer (score 0):

In case of comparing lists I highly recommend to move to assertJ: http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/

Using that that assert would be:

```
Assertions.assertThat(actualList).containsAll(expectedList);
```

Comment: Changing the method for checking if the two lists are equal does not really apply here. `Assert.assertEquals` does the trick.